# Unexpected behavior from integer checking in C

Tags: c, string, integer, type-conversion

This is what I wrote to check if input is a positive integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isInt(char num[3]) {
    int l = strlen(num);
    int x;

    for ( x = 0; x < l; x++) {
        if ( ! isdigit(num[x]) )
            return 0;        
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char str[3];

    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    if ( isInt(str) == 1 ) {
        i = atoi(str);
        printf("%d \n", i);
    } else {
        printf("This is not a positive integer! \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I found some unexpected behaviors, even though the program seems to work:

1. Whether I `#include <ctype.h>` or not it makes no difference. How can `isdigit()` function work without its library? (I'm on ubuntu 14.04 using gcc 4.9.3)
2. if I impose `str` to be a a string of length 3 how is it possible that when I run `./a.out` it checks correctly and prints also numbers bigger than 999? If I input 5678 shouldn't `str` only save 567? Or maybe it saves the first 2^3 digits? I'm confused
3. if I want to check if a string is a positive integer but the number could be very big, how big should `str` be? Isn't there a way to make it as big as needed?

Comment: It's better to ask one question per time. And most of your questions have their duplicate asked before, search the site first.

Comment: Out-of-bounds write, undefined behavior.

Comment: code build is not in your favor, as out of bound is giving working result.

Comment: You can use dynamic memory allocation, and `realloc()` as necessary.

Comment: `int l = strlen(num);` is wrong should be `size_t l = strlen(num);` also `scanf("%s", str);` should be `scanf("%2s", str);`

Comment: If you're running in a POSIX environment you can use `getline()`. It dynamically allocates an input buffer that's big enough and returns a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

1. A header file is not a library; it only says how to use a library. If you omit the header file then the compiler will have to guess what parameters the functions take, but if it guesses right (or close enough) then all may appear to work fine. (Actually it doesn't "guess"; there are rules, of course.)
2. You didn't "impose" a limit on the length of `str`, you reserved 3 bytes of space. If you overrun that reservation then the program may (or may not) continue to work fine, but you might find other data has unexpectedly been corrupted. There's no reliable way to predict what data will get overwritten; it's undefined.
3. No, there's no way to know how big the number will be before the user enters it, but you can set the maximum number of character that will be read by using `%3s`, for example. However, you need to make sure you reserve enough space for the `'\0'` nul-character terminator at the end of the string. You can also use an alternative to `scanf` to read the data in chunks, but you're probably safest just to use a "large" buffer and the maximum field width. Note that scanf can read numbers directly without you reading it as a string and then converting it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding point 3:

No, there is no way to know in advance.

However, it is easy to make a function that reads the input in smaller portions and concatenates them into a big buffer. The big buffer will be allocated dynamically so it can grow when need. The user must call free.

Here is one implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INCREMENT_SIZE 20
#define SMALL_SIZE 10

char* read_long_string(void)
{
  char* all;
  char* tmp;
  int all_size;
  char some[SMALL_SIZE];

  all_size = INCREMENT_SIZE;
  all = malloc(all_size);
  if (!all)
  {
    // Out of mem
    return NULL;
  }
  all[0] = '\0';

  while(1)
  {
    // Make sure "all" has room for all bytes in "some"
    while(all_size - strlen(all) < sizeof(some))
    {
      all_size += INCREMENT_SIZE;
      tmp = realloc(all, all_size);  // Allocate more memory
      if (!tmp)
      {
        // Out of mem
        free(all);
        return NULL;
      }
      all = tmp;
    }

    // Read bytes into "some"
    if (!fgets(some, sizeof(some), stdin))
    {
      // Error
      free(all);
      return NULL;
    }

    if (strlen(some) > 0)
    {
      // Add the bytes to "all"
      strcat(all, some);

      // Check if newline has been pressed
      if (some[strlen(some)-1] == '\n')
      {
        // done
        return all;
      }

    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char* s;

  printf("Enter a positive integer:\n");
  s = read_long_string();
  if (s) printf("%s", s);

  free(s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calling `strlen()` on an uninitialized `malloc()`ed buffer is not a good idea.

Comment: Well, it's still a ridiculously convoluted Rube-Goldberg-Schlemiel contraption, but I suppose it's *technically* correct now.

Comment: @EOF - If you know a better solution to the problem, please post it. That will be more helpful than just calling another solution "ridiculously convoluted"